# Multiple traps in the same bash process

Tags: bash, shell, signals

I want to put couple of function into my `.bashrc`.
The functions may execute for a long time so I'd like to be able to kill them with `CTRL+C` and print some information when this happens. I can capture `CTRL+C` by trapping `SIGINT` but I'm not sure what is the correct way to set different trap handlers for different functions inside the same script (`.bashrc`).

I came up with this solution which seems to work:

```sh
function foo()
{
    trap 'echo "foo() stopped"' SIGINT
    while true; do
        sleep 1
        echo "foo() working..."
    done
}

function bar()
{
    trap 'echo "bar() stopped"' SIGINT
    while true; do
        sleep 1
        echo "bar() working..."
    done
}
```

Example output:

```
$ foo
foo() working...
foo() working...
^Cfoo() stopped

$ bar
bar() working...
bar() working...
^Cbar() stopped
```

Now, my questions are:

1. Am I understanding correctly that each time I do `trap ...` inside a function it resets signal handler for the whole bash session (process)? Or is it creating a new handler each time?
2. Is this a good solution in general, or is there better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the trap is resetting things globally.  It would probably be good to reset it to its original value when the function ends.  Something like:

```
foo() {
        old=$(trap -p SIGINT)
        trap 'echo "foo() stopped"' SIGINT
        ...
        eval set -- "$old"
        trap "$3" SIGINT
}
```

OTOH, it's probably more robust to run the function as a subshell, which would have the effect of only setting the trap for the subshell.  Doing this is as simple as using `(` and `)` in the function definition:

```
foo()
(
    trap 'echo "foo() stopped"' SIGINT
    while true; do
        sleep 1
        echo "foo() working..."
    done
)
```

Comment: Subshell is a nice idea and offers some "isolation" that I was exactly looking for.